# Can a concerted effort be made by one person?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I believe that, in the same way as a *concert* is a performance of a group (if it's a soloist, then it's a *recital*), a concerted effort is also a collective business. But I'm not quite sure. Maybe, when you "force your heart and nerve and sinew" (*If* by R.Kipling), it's also a *concerted effort*?

Comment: If you're going to be technical then you're right -- "concerted effort" requires more than one individual.  But the idiom "concerted effort" has acquired a secondary meaning of "intense effort".

Comment: 3260 written instances of [he made a concerted effort](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+made+a+concerted+effort%22) suggest there's no reason why a single person can't make a concerted effort. Personally I don't see it as particularly "illogical" anyway - since you can obviously *pull yourself together*, and *use all your powers* to deal with a problem, it seems quite reasonable to assume a single person can be represented as a potential multiplicity in such contexts.

Comment: Thank you, Fumbled Fingers. In fact, what you said confirmed my supposition, supported by Kipling, that internal concentration is also kind of concerted. At the same time, here is what Wikipedia has, "The Oxford English Dictionary defines the adjective “concerted” as meaning “arranged by mutual agreement; agreed upon, pre-arranged; planned, contrived; done in concert.”  So, even though the modern usage permits  "concerted" as "concentrated", the doubt I raised has some conservative legitimization.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That looks like a good answer. Would you like to convert it to one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can.  The definition of the verb "[to concert](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concert?s=t)" is:

> verb (used with object)
>
> 7. to contrive or arrange by agreement: "They were able to concert a settlement of their differences."
> 8. to plan; devise: "A program of action was concerted at the meeting."
>
> verb (used without object)
>
> 9. to plan or act together.

Based on definition 8 above, it clearly can be used without others being involved.  For example:

> The boy made a *planned* effort to turn in his homework on time.
>
> The boy made a *devised* effort to turn in his homework on time.
>
> The boy made a *concerted* effort to turn in his homework on time.

I suppose that just as a singular person can disconcert himself, so can he concert himself.  I'm being tongue-in-cheek, of course.  I realize that much like pertinent and impertinent are not opposites, neither are concert and disconcert.  Such foray is only to demonstrate that words are not always what they seem at first blush.

Comment: Yes. If I am sleeping in and late for work all the time, and I decide to address that problem by 1) going to bed 2 hours earlier, 2) waking up an hour earlier, 3) buying a better alarm clock, and 4) getting a colleague to pick me up and drive me to work, then I have certainly made a *concerted* effort not to be late. The concert is the 4 things I did, not 4 people.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entry for *concerted*, as an adjective, from *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **concerted** *adj* (1706)  **1 a :** mutually contrived or agreed on {a *concerted* effort} **b :** performed in unison {*concerted* artillery fire} **2 :** arranged in parts for several voices or instruments

Here's the corresponding definition from *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fourth edition (2000):

> **concerted** *adj.* **1.** Planned or accomplished together; combined: *We made a concerted effort to solve the problem.* **2.** *Music* Arranged in parts for voices or instruments.

And from *Encarta World English Dictionary* (1999):

> **concerted** *adj.* **1.** achieved or planned together; planned or carried out by two or more people working together or with the same goal **2.** *Music* arranged for orchestra or chamber ensemble; written for several soloists to perform together in an ensemble, or within the context of a larger-scale work.

And from *Oxford American Dictionary and Thesaurus* (2003):

> **concerted** *adj.* **1** combined together; jointly arranged or planned (*a concerted effort*) **2** *Mus.* arranged in parts for voices or instruments

In these definitions I don't find any evidence of the applicability of *concerted* to things done "by one person" (to quote the heading of the poster's question). To the contrary, the emphasis is on mutual or united effort by multiple people (or other entities). Nevertheless, Google Books search results do turn up instances such as this one, from Jo Sanders, "[How Do We Get Educators to Teach Gender Equality?](https://books.google.com/books?id=9--hvR8zT7oC&pg=PA226&dq=%22I+have+made+a+concerted%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwvv_F0MbKAhVC1mMKHUK1B2EQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22I%20have%20made%20a%20concerted%22&f=false)" in *Equity in the Classroom: Towards Effective Pedagogy for Girls and Boys* (1996):

> I have made a **concerted** effort not to assume that a male science or mathematics teacher is more knowledgeable merely because he is a he. (New York)

The intended sense of *concerted* here is evidently something like "focused, intensive, prolonged, single-minded, or dedicated"—a sense that contrasts rather sharply with the collaborative sense that *concerted* has traditionally possessed. Why do instances like this one occur? I think that they are attributable to a simple misfire: the writer or speaker means something much closer to *concentrated*—that is (to adapt the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s third definition of the verb *concentrate*), "having one's powers, efforts, or attention focused [on some object or purpose]."

Eventually, if speakers and writers commit a particular this-for-that blunder—such as using *concerted* for *concentrated*—often enough, it achieves critical mass in usage and becomes a new accepted meaning of the misapplied word, instead of just being a mistake; but I don't think we've reached that point quite yet with *concerted* in the sense of "concentrated." At least in the short term, I would use "a *concerted* effort" for an effort undertaken collectively and "a *concentrated* [or *focused*] effort" for an effort undertaken individually and with an unusually high level of focus.

Comment: No, they didn’t mean “concentrated” — that is a whole different idea.

Comment: I think that the New York teacher's "concerted effort not to assume that a male science or mathematics teacher is more knowledgeable merely because he is a he" (in my answer) doesn't involve combining multiple ideas or actions—that is, working in concert with oneself. It involves concentrating or focusing on one thing: resisting making an inappropriate assumption that leads to unwarranted favoritism. To me, _concerted_ resembles _coordinated_: it's possible to say that some plan involves coordinating with oneself, but the usage is odd and not fully established at the dictionary level.

Answer (score 0):

It means the focus and drawing upon all of one's strengths to make the effort.  So the concert is the harmonizing of one's mind, body, soul, energies together to accomplish a difficult task.  This is a case where a half hearted effort simply will not be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the point of the argument here rests in the usage of the word itself. Concert does in all the above definitions hint to being more than one party. However I also argue the point of oxymorons (thou they are usually dual words and opposites) one could say out of sarcastic intent a concerted effort. This would be in a high informational exchange where both parties understand one person is performing the task and the performer of that task knows it's a lot of work. As if to say me and mine will be/have this done.